# Count the number of rows in one table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some problems with counting the size of a table of my table.

I want to know how many 'inputs'? I guess are in there so I can present the total number of 'users' on my admin panel.

I tried looking at another question and here is what I created out of it.

I am not the best with PHP, I was wondering if anyone could answer my question.

```
$connect = mysql_connect('****.com','****User','****Pass') or die("Error");
mysql_select_db('****Database') or die("Error");
$data = "SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS num FROM `UserDB`";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$numUsers = $row['num'];
mysql_query($data,$connect);
mysql_close($connect);
echo $numUsers;
```

Comment: you're supposed to call mysql_query before mysql_fetch_assoc ... but more precisely you should not be using mysql_ functions. Instead switch to mysqli or PDO

Comment: Im not sure how to swap, im using free webhost 000webhost.com and im not sure if they give me the option, or how to change.
Could you help me out? :)

Comment: I added a response as an answer. It won't help you if you don't have access to the file. I assume you must though. Someone had to write this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe only help I can give you is showing you what I mean by swap...

```
$connect = mysql_connect('****.com','****User','****Pass') or die("Error");
mysql_select_db('****Database') or die("Error");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS num FROM `UserDB`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$numUsers = $row['num'];
mysql_close($connect);
echo $numUsers;
```

As for how to manage whatever free host, I can only suggest you contact them and ask how to update the file in question, assuming that was your point of the comment. If not, feel free to clarify.

Comment: Brilliant, im not sure what i did wronb but thanks!
It now echos the size of my table, thanks a bunch mate :) Saved me some time!

Answer (score 1):

change your query to this

```
   $data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS num FROM `UserDB`");
```

OBS: please consider to learn mysqli or PDO